# C++ Constructor Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, constructor, segmentation-fault

```
BST() {
    root = new BST();
    right = NULL;
    left = NULL;
};
private:
BST *right, *left;
BST *root;

main:
BST bst1;
```

Segmentation Fault: 11
Is the constructor getting into an infinite loop?
I tried static variable to call constructor once, but it didn't work. How to handle this?

Comment: Yes, your constructor is infinitely recursive. Why should `root` be a new instance of `BST`?

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration

```
BST bst1;
```

there is called the default constructor of the class BST that within itself again calls itself in this statement

```
root = new BST();
```

So you have infinite recursive calls of the constructor.

Your declaration of BST does not make a sense.

Declare it at least like

```
class BST
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node *left  = nullptr;
        Node *right = nullptr;
        // some data member for stored data
    } *root = nullptr;

public:
    BST() = default;
    // other declarations
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set root to `nullptr` instead of creating a new BST object. Then initialize it when you need it.